# xml-validator doesn't work

Tags: xml, xml-validation

I tried to check this document at xml validator into Firefox.
But this cheking was successful.
And I want to know why? Here is some mistake accordings DTD:

`from CDATA   #FIXED "Kathy Shepherd"`

and after this at `note` - `from="someone else">`

Maybe exist, some another way for validation xml document at browser.

**Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE note      [
<!ELEMENT note      (message)>
<!ELEMENT message   (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST message
         number CDATA #REQUIRED
         date CDATA   #REQUIRED
         from CDATA   #FIXED "Kathy Shepherd">
                    ]>
<note>
    <message number="10" date="041513" from="someone else">
        Remember to buy milk on the way home from work
    </message>
</note>
```

**Question:**

- How to make this XML-checking at correct way (maybe at some others
  browsers)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web browsers don't implement validating XML parsers. They only care if a document is well-formed or not.

If you want to perform validation, use a validator such as the [W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: What can you said about - [Microsoft’s Free XML Editor](http://razorleaf.com/2010/09/microsofts-free-xml-editor/)? Can we use it with this aim?

Comment: Nothing. I've never used it.